# Covert columns to rows in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with multiple columns as following:

```
+-------+------+------+------+
| Name  | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+-------+------+------+------+
| pinki | a    | b    | c    |
+-------+------+------+------+
```

How do I convert columns into rows and achieve output table like below-

```
+-------+-----+
| Name  | col |
+-------+-----+
| Pinki | a   |
| Pinki | b   |
| Pinki | c   |
+-------+-----+
```

Test table -

```
create table testing(
Name varchar(10),
col1 varchar(10),
col2 varchar(10),
col3 varchar(10));

insert into testing(Name,col1,col2,col3) values ('pinki','a','b','c');
```

Comment: Google your title and you will find lots of examples.(and it's good practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all`

```
select name, col1 as col from testing
union all
select name, col2  from testing
union all
select name, col3  from testing
```

Comment: thats too quick. :-)  . Can we achieve this using unpivot also?

Comment: in mysql there is no pivot & unpivot @PinkiSharma

Comment: @KiranDesai, sql is just a lnaguage I am talking about product i mean database. And you know what I know that this question is for sql :)